# Laravel quick integer lookup?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

We have a table with millions of rows. Recently we introduced an integer to act as a secondary key, which is just a unique integer column `new_identifier = 1100327` and not yet defined as a secondary primary key.

This lookup query takes about 6 seconds in tinker. `$this->id_lookup` is also an integer. and up to 50 seconds on horizon!

`DB::table('my_big_table')->where('new_identifier', $this->id_lookup)->get();`

How can we achieve the same performance as `DB::table('my_big_table')->find($this->id_lookup);` which is almost instant?

Can we introduce a second primary key with something like `$table->key(['id', 'new_identifier']);`?

How would this effect other lookups like `MyBigTable::find($id);` that is performed elsewhere?

Update - changing column from int to index reduced lookup time from 50s to <0.01s

Comment: May be PARTITIONS.

Comment: That's what we are thinking. We have a second table with the same number of records and searching by 32 character hash is almost instant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an index, do the following in a migration.

```
Schema::table('my_big_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index('new_identifier');
});
```

An index can help you, but primary key indexes are special, they are clustered. Which means it contains all data on the following key. While secondary indexes non clustered, only will contain the indexed columns and the primary key column. It will still improve performances, but is an area where you need to research a lot about what the impact of different indexes will perform on queries and is not at all black and white.

Comment: This could be another question, but do `unique` indexes performs better than just `index` ?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to reread the  [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) when i read your statement about  secondary indexes -> *" All indexes other than the clustered index are known as secondary indexes. In InnoDB, each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index. InnoDB uses this primary key value to search for the row in the clustered index.

If the primary key is long, the secondary indexes use more space, so it is advantageous to have a short primary key. "*

Comment: is `index` represented by `bigInt`?

Comment: @Raymond Nijland took on top of the head from my schools text book :) but thanks updated the wording.

Comment: is `index` query also done with ` ->where('new_id, $newId);` ?

Comment: "is index query also done with ` ->where('new_id, $newId);`" compares to what indexes you have, if you have an index with new_id yes

Comment: Update - changing column from `int` to `index` reduced lookup time from 50s to <0.01s

Comment: You did not change the column, index is a mapping of your table that increases the speed :)